# find two identical data points, then return values relating to the second data point into the first

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two work sheets. I would like to select a cell in the first work sheet and IF the contents are matched within the second work sheet, take data from that row (in the second sheet) and place it in defined cells in the first sheet.

the column order will always remain the same in both work sheets.

for example.

Sheet 1

Columns = UID, A, B, C, D, E, F, G

Sheet 2

Columns = UID, 1,2,D,E,F,G

I want to select a cell in column 'UID' in sheet 1 and check the column 'UID' in sheet 2. if two items match, I would like to take the data within columns D,E,F,G (for the row that UID row that matched) in sheet 2 and return it to columns D,E,F,G in sheet 1 (for the row that matched).

Sorry if i have not explained it as well as needed.

Many thanks

Comment: Consider using the Excel **=VLOOKUP()** worksheet function.

Comment: thanks both - afraid it always comes back with an error. everything i have read seems to tell me it will only bring back one value rather than 3 or 4 cells worth

Answer (score 0):

> afraid it always comes back with an error. everything i have read seems to tell me it will only >bring back one value rather than 3 or 4 cells worth

What if you concatenated all the columns into one column in sheet two, using a standard delimiter (e.g. / or # or whatever character isn't in your data).  Then do your vloookup.  To get the final result use the text to columns tool to un-concatenate the data.